# Differential equation type

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation
$$(1 + x^2)(1+y^2)\mathrm dx +xy\mathrm dy = 0$$

It doesn't look like separable and I don't think it's neither homogenous.

Maybe I need to use the integration multiplier to solve it? I just need to know which way I should go about it, I don't need it solved.

Comment: It is separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(1+x^2)(1+y^2)\,dx + xy\,dy = 0 \implies \frac{(1+x^2)}{x}\,dx = -\frac{y}{1+y^2}\,dy.$$

Comment: OK, that was all i needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: Serial downvoters?

Comment: @AlexSilva Apparently yes, what's with them, huh? Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{(1 + x^2)}{x} dx = - \frac{y}{(1 + y^2)}dy$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Don't understand these downvoters.